# How to read json file from storage blob container with azure function using javascript?

Tags: javascript, azure-functions

I'm totally new in azure and I would like to create azure function, which will read the content from azure storage container file.json.

Folder structure :
Storage account name: storageaccounttest
Container name: test
File name: file.json

File.json:

```
[

    {
        "name":"Kate",
        "age":"28"
    },
    {
        "name":"John",
        "age":"30"
    }
]
```

Cors on storage account: get enabled.

Environemnts variable added: process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_NAME and process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_KEY and process.env.AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING

I'm using VisualStudioCode to deploy the function.
I installed locally the dependencies: 
"dependencies": {
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0"
  }

I choose the javascript -> HttpTrigger fn-> anonymus options

I'm using getBlobToText fn.
My index.js:

```
var storage = require('azure-storage');
var blobService = storage.createBlobService();
var containerName = 'test';
var blobName = 'file.json';

module.exports =  blobService.getBlobToText(
    containerName,
    blobName,
    function(err, blobContent) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Couldn't download blob");
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Sucessfully downloaded blob");
            console.log(blobContent);
        }
    });
```

Fn is deployed successfully, but I'm not able to see results.
After start, fn is finished with status 500, Internal Server Errror, Console: No new trace in the past 1 min(s).

What I made wrong?

Comment: Is it working locally ? If yes, Make sure you have added a relevant App setting for Storage in the Portal App settings blade.

Comment: yes, locally it is working correctly. Which settings do you mean?

Comment: ok I did it with context.bindings

Answer (score 2):

Just summarized for helping others who get the same issue.

I think you were using `context.binding.response` to pass the `blobContent` value to the output response as the offical document [`Azure Functions JavaScript developer guide`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#http-triggers-and-bindings) said.

Here is my sample code with `Promise` feature to solve it.

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var blobService = azure.createBlobService();
var containerName = 'test';
var blobName = 'file.json';

async function getBlobContent(containerName, blobName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    blobService.getBlobToText(containerName, blobName, function(err, blobContent) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(blobContent);
        }
    });
  });
}

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    await getBlobContent(containerName, blobName).then(
        function(content) {
            context.res = {
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: content
            }
        }, function(error) {
            context.res = {
                status: 400,
                body: error
            }
        }
    );
};
```

It works as the figure below.

[image]